# HTML form doesn't capture all the checkboxes from Bootstrap responsive table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which displays results from my DB. In the last column I have checkboxes and by clicking submit button I am sending an array of account_id's to another php file. Everything works fine but the problem is that I am using a Bootstrap responsive table which can show 10-100 results on each page and the form only captures results on the current page. If I check boxes on different pages and switch between them, they still remain checked, though.
Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="compare.php" method="post">
<table class="table table-hover" id="dataTables-example">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Account name</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Address</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Phone number</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Website</th>
            <th style="text-align:center;">Compare</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>                                
        <?php 
        $result= mysql_query("select * from accounts order by account_name ASC" ) or die (mysql_error());
        while ($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result) ){                                 
        ?>
        <tr>
            <td class='clickable-row' data-href="select.php?id=<?php echo $row ['account_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row ['account_name'];?></td>
            <td class='clickable-row' data-href="select.php?id=<?php echo $row ['account_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row ['address']; ?></td>
            <td class='clickable-row' data-href="select.php?id=<?php echo $row ['account_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row ['phone_number']; ?></td>
            <td class='clickable-row' data-href="select.php?id=<?php echo $row ['account_id'];?>"> <?php echo $row ['website']; ?></td>
            <td> <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxvar[]" value="<?php echo $row ['account_id'];?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>

    </tbody>
</table>
<input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Compare" id="submit">
</form>
```

I tried to use jQuery to see if it can capture the checkboxes from the whole table, but results is the same as trying an HTML form.
This script is supposed to capture them and make an alert:

```
<button id="bt1">Get</button>

<script>

$('#bt1').on('click', function () {
//Get checked checkboxes
var checkedCheckboxes = $("#dataTables-example :checkbox:checked"),
    arr = [];

//For each checkbox
for (var i = 0; i < checkedCheckboxes.length; i++) {

    //Get checkbox
    var checkbox = $(checkedCheckboxes[i]);

    //Get checkbox value
    var checkboxValue = checkbox.val();

    //Get siblings
    var siblings = checkbox.parent().siblings();

    //Get values of siblings
    var value1 = $(siblings[0]).text();
    var value2 = $(siblings[1]).text();

    arr.push(checkboxValue + '-' + value1 + '/' + value2);
     alert(checkboxValue + '-' + value1 + '/' + value2);
}
});

</script>
```

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

Include this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/f2c75b7247b/api/fnGetHiddenNodes.js"></script>
```

And this paste this function:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
oTable = $('#yourTableID').dataTable();

$('form').submit(function(){
   $(oTable.fnGetHiddenNodes()).find('input:checked').appendTo(this);
}); 
});
</script>
```

All checkboxes are captured by clicking submit button.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Datatables object:

```
$('input', oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {
  if($(this).is('checked')){
    console.log($(this).val());
  }
});
```

Comment: If I only knew how to use it. I am completely new to this.

Comment: Show the javascript code you're loading Datatables.

Comment: You don't need to add extra javascript code on you page. The Datatables library already have all the functions you need and seems like the function you posted as solution will just get hidden pages checkboxes from table.